# Changing color for appended table thru anchor in loop always changes color for last item JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a js variable, `table_data` which contains html table data with one anchor link.

```
var table_data = '<table><thead><tr><th>head</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td>@body</td></tr></tbody></table><a href="#" class="btnAddNewInputType">add</a>
```

I have a javascript array.

```
var arr= [3,2,2,1,1];
```

According to this array i append `table_data` inside a div already placed in html code id: `TableDiv`.

```
  for (var p = 0; p < arr.length; p++) {
     var result = table_data.replace("@", p + 1);
     var $newHtml = $(result);
     var a = $newHtml.find("a.btnAddNewInputType");
     a.click(function () {
     $newHtml.css("background-color","yellow");
            });
  jQuery("#TableDiv").append($newHtml);
}
```

This loop creates `arr.length` number of tables each having `a.btnAddNewInputType` anchor tag with it.

BUT whenever i click the anchor tag for say 1st table, the color of the last table changes. It happens with all the table's anchor tag.

I want anchor click to change color of their respective table not the last one.

Thanks

Comment: Could you recreate the issue (in snippet or jsfiddle)?

Answer (score 0):

You should use current element context i.e. `this` and its relationship to target DOM. Here you can use `.prev()` also use [Event Delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) using [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) delegated-events approach, when generating elements dynamically.

```
jQuery("#TableDiv").on('click', "a.btnAddNewInputType", function(e) {
  $(this).prev('table').css("background-color", "yellow");
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```js
var table_data = '<table><thead><tr><th>head</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td>@body</td></tr></tbody></table><a href="#" class="btnAddNewInputType">add</a>';

var arr = [3, 2, 2, 1, 1];
for (var p = 0; p < arr.length; p++) {
  var result = table_data.replace("@", p + 1);
  jQuery("#TableDiv").append($(result));
}

jQuery("#TableDiv").on('click', "a.btnAddNewInputType", function(e) {
  $(this).prev('table').css("background-color", "yellow");
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="TableDiv"></div>
```

Comment: Hi satpal, Thank for answering. but this will change the color of the anchor  tag not the table.

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<div id="TableDiv"></div>
```

Js:

```
var table_data = '<table><thead><tr><th>head</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td>@body</td></tr></tbody></table><a href="#" class="btnAddNewInputType">add</a>';

var arr = [3, 2, 2, 1, 1];

for (var p = 0; p < arr.length; p++) {
  var result = table_data.replace("@", p + 1);
  var $newHtml = $(result);
  jQuery("#TableDiv").append($newHtml);
}

$("#TableDiv").on("click", "a.btnAddNewInputType", function() {  
  $(this).prev("table").css("background-color", "yellow");
});
```